# Call https page via .vbs script fails ... why?

Tags: vbscript, https, scheduled-tasks

Here's the script.  Tried executing by itself ... nada.  Tried executing via task scheduler ... nada.  If I hit the URL below via IE it works.  Any ideas???

```
''//Force the script to finish on an error.
On Error Resume Next

''//Declare variables
Dim objRequest
Dim URL

Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

''//Put together the URL link appending the Variables.
URL = "https://myurlhere.com"

''//Open the HTTP request and pass the URL to the objRequest object
objRequest.open "GET", URL , false

''//Send the HTML Request
objRequest.Send

''//Set the object to nothing
Set objRequest = Nothing
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that the page was requiring windows authentication and even though the script was running as an authenticated user ... it was failing due to not responding with a username and password when asked.

Solution:
* Enable anonymous authentication
* Update web.config so that notification controller didn't require an authenticated user

Comment: Turning off Windows Authentication isn't really the answer.
Suppose your site has it turned on for a reason!

Answer (score 0):

"In Internet Explorer 8, the VBScript syntax is not supported"

-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28VS.85%29.aspx

Could this be the problem?

Comment: No this isn't the problem.  What I meant above is that I can go to the URL "https://myurlhere.com" from a browser ... what I can't do is get there by running the vbs script above.  I'm running both under the same credentials.